# Why encrypted internet connections can't be censored or blocked by a country willing to do it?

Tags: network, privacy, man-in-the-middle, government, censorship

Is it possible for a country to restrict any encrypted internet connection to some computer outside of the country, or if absolutely necessary just use a mitm(man-in-the-middle) to guarantee they can see the content? I know that the user will know that the connection are being spied because of the invalid certificate from the ca(certificate authority), but the user in this situation would have no option but to comply, if they absolutely need to connect to the computer outside of that country, I know that the user can always use steganography if encryption is not allowed, but steganography is too slow for internet access nowadays, is my reasoning flawed in some aspect? is the economical cost too much? I'm not advocating for censorship, I just want to understand what limitations the current anti-censorship tools have

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a country block/censor an encrypted website (HTTPS)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64568/how-does-a-country-block-censor-an-encrypted-website-https), [How can authoritarian governments sniff TLS encrypted traffic on mass scale?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/265316/how-can-authoritarian-governments-sniff-tls-encrypted-traffic-on-mass-scale)

Comment: Your question title seems to imply that it is impossible - yet your question content implies that it can be done but with limitations. Please align title and question so that they ask the same.